# Where should i put view builder method method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, mvvm, refactoring

I'm refactoring an app from MVC to MVVM, and have methods which return an UIView*. Where should i put this method? is it on View or ViewController.

```c
- (UIView *)viewWithText:(NSString *)titleString {
    // code that build a UIView* without any communication with view model
}

- (UIView *)buildView :(NSString *)titleString {
    // code that build UIView* with communication with view model
}
```

Comment: you can put it in service class (some common class) if this method is used in multiple classes or modules. If it is only for one view controller then you can put in view model or view controller!

Comment: why view model ? isn't the view model should only handle logic and data?

Comment: yup! a view model is responsible for all the business logic. but if you have some method which returns view then you can put it in view model or keep it in view controller itself. there is nothing like thumb rule in design patterns!

Comment: okay, i thin i should put it in view controller for a cleaner code structure, thank you